# Default data type variable for loop in C

Tags: c

In C, what is the default data type for a variable defined in a loop?

```
for(k = 0; expression2; expression3) {
}
```

is valid and so is

```
for(int k = 0; expression2; expression3) {
}
```

If I don't specify the data type for the variable `k`, what does the compiler do?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 2):

In the current C standard (C11, but this is true for C99 too), there is no "implicit" type.

Different compilers will report the error in different ways. GCC says:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:2:9: error: ‘k’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     for(k=0;k<2;k++) {
         ^
test.c:2:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

In C89/C90 there was an "implicit int" rule, but that does not apply in this case. Here, unless the variable was declared before, it is a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

> If I don't specify the data type for the variable k, what does the compiler do?

There's no *default* type for variables defined in the for loop's initialization. It's just a syntax error in all C standards.

Since C99 you are allowed to declare variable in for loop's initialization part and before C99, you'll have to declare it outside the loop and only allowed at the beginning of a scope.

```
/* Allowed in C99 and above */
for(int k = 0; expression2; expression3) {
}
```

and:

```
/* Unless k is defined before, this is a syntax error */
for(k = 0; expression2; expression3) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called default data type ..!! 
   We have to specify the **type of data** according to what type of data we are accessing on.
     And if we don't specify the data type the compiler pops up compile time error stating that particular variable is **undeclared**